# Loading a model into a scene with JAssimp?

Tags: java, opengl, assimp

I'm trying to go along with [this tutorial page](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial22/tutorial22.html) in LWJGL. I've done the previous tutorials with great results, but I'm a bit stuck here.

Specifically, on this line:

```
    const aiScene* pScene = Importer.ReadFile(Filename.c_str(),    aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_GenSmoothNormals | aiProcess_FlipUVs);
```

I'm using [this](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/tree/master/port/jassimp) port of Assimp for Java, and it seems to not have an Importer class. I've scoured the API, and nothing comes up.

Does anyone know how I would import the mesh, or replicate what is done in the tutorial?